# Invalid number of arguments in "location" nginx conf

Tags: docker, nginx

I am trying to use nginx as reverse proxy for simple "Hello world" flask app. I am running them in different docker containers and use docker compose to build.

When I used docker-compose up --build command I got this error from nginx:

invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:6

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location  {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }

}
```

Can someone say what did I do wrong?

Comment: See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), but `location` requires a value between the directive and the opening brace. For example: `location / { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a / directly after the location directive. A clearer error message would be "The location directive is missing an argument".

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass flask:8080;
    }

}
```